# Download RData from bitbucket private repo using R

Tags: r, git, bitbucket

I am trying to import a .RData from my own bitbucket private repo to Rstudio. I tried googling but I seem to get answers about GitHub. While useful, the techniques do not discuss about private repos. Some help would be great. I tried several ways but it isn't working.

1.

```
x <- read.csv( curl("https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/data-sets.git/DataSets/xxx.csv") )
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : HTTP error 404.
```

2

```
url <- "https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/data-sets/DataSets/xxx.csv)"
 download.file(url, "myfile")

 trying URL 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/data-sets/DataSets/xxx.csv)'
  Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length 32376 bytes (31 KB)
  downloaded 31 KB

load("myfile")

Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded 
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘myfile’ has magic number '<!DOC'
Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

3

```
 load(url(url))
 Error: the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection
```